# Question about CALL statement

Tags: assembly

I have the following code in VC++

```
Func5(){ StackWalk(); }
Func4{ Func5();}
```

I am a Beginner in x86 Assembly Language. I am trying to find out the starting address of Func5(). I get the Func5()'s return address from its stack frame. Now before this return address there should be a CALL statement. So I extract out the bytes before the return address.

Sometimes it's a near call like `E8 ff ff ff d8`. So for this statement I subtract the offset 0x28 from the function's return address to get Func5()'s base address (where it resides in memory).

The problem is I don't know how to calculate this for a indirect NEAR call. I have been trying to find out how to do it for some time now. So I have extracted out the first 5 bytes before the return address and they are `ff 75 08 ff d2` I think this stands for `CALL ECX (ff d2)` but I am not sure.

I will be very grateful if someone can tell me what kind of CALL statement this is and how I can calculate the function's base address from this kind of call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For disassembling things, the easiest way is to use a disassembler.

Assuming 32-bit 80x86, NDISASM says "ff 75 08 ff d2" is:

```
00000000  FF7508            push dword [ebp+0x8]
00000003  FFD2              call edx
```

In this case, the address of the function will be in the EDX register.

Comment: Can you suggest a debugger for Windows please.

Comment: I haven't used Windows for software development about 8 years, so I don't think I'm the best person to ask about Windows debuggers. Back when I used to use Windows98 I used NASM/NDISASM. Now that I'm doing all my development work on Linux I'm still using NASM/NDISASM (but most of my work is raw binary files, not Windows/PE files).

Comment: Just a quick extra note - for the purpose of learning assembly, I'd probably recommend some sort of interactive debugger (something that lets you examine the contents of registers, memory, etc as you "single-step" or execute one instruction at a time).

Comment: I found another CALL instruction FF 15 34 73 58 00. Does this mean jump to address 0x00587334?

Comment: That would be "call dword near [dword 0x00587334]", where the memory at the address 0x00587334 contains the address of the routine to call.

Answer (score 1):

Tell the compiler and linker to generate a detailed map file. I don't know about recent versions, but it used to be possible to request an assembly-language dump of the linking, opcodes included.